# the CAPTCHA decoding program is giving Unsupported image object

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, captcha, python-tesseract

```
captcha_img_src = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "captcha-img").get_attribute("src")

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

# Check if the directory exists

if not os.path.exists("Images_act"):
os.makedirs("Images_act")

    image_base64 = captcha_img_src.split(",")\[1\]

# Decode the base64 image and save it to a file

with open("Images_act/new.jpeg", "wb") as image_file:  
    image_file.write(base64.b64decode(image_base64))

# Load the captcha image

captcha_image = cv2.imread('Images_act/new.jpeg')

# Enhance preprocessing (convert to grayscale, resize, and threshold)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(captcha_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
resized = cv2.resize(gray, None, fx=2, fy=2,         interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
\_, thresholded = cv2.threshold(resized, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Perform OCR using Tesseract

captcha_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresholded)
```

I tried reinstalling libraries , it was working earlier but now i am stuck .

Comment: please include the error message in your question.